# "int object is not callable" when trying to open pickle file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am working for a team of scientists and have been given a pickle file we'll call `theFile.p`. I am trying to open and load the Pickle file via

```
opened_file = open("theFile.p", "rb")
loaded_data = pickle.load(opened_file)
```

but am getting the error

```
    loaded_data = pickle.load(opened_file)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Now I know that error means you either forgot an arithmetic operator somewhere or you declared a variable name that matches a built in function name (e.g. `max = max(1, 2)`).
I am wondering if this means there is some sort of issue inside the `theFile.p` that's causing this error, and if so, how would I go about debugging the Pickle file if I can't even open it? Or maybe it's an issue with me being on Python 3.11 and the pickle file was made on an older version Python?

Full traceback can be seen here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1499, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/Todo/Test/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/Todo/Test/main.py", line 7, in main
    loaded_file = pickle.load(opened_file)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you checked `type(pickle)`, `type(pickle.load)`, and `type(opened_file)` to ensure that they haven't been overwritten elsewhere in the code?

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for the response! I have checked them. `type(pickle)` is `<class 'module'>` and `type(pickle.load)` is `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` and `type(opened_file)` is `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>`. None of them are of `int` type unfortunately

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Is the line that prints the type right before the call that gets the error?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar! The trace-back can be seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/0T3i8jx)

Comment: What happens if you run the script normally instead of from PyCharm?

Comment: If I run the script from a regular Mac terminal I get the same error

Comment: @AndrewJones Please edit your question and provide the traceback as text, not as an image elsewhere.  Questions work best when they are standalone.

Comment: Is there more context?  It does seem your error is impossible; however the pickle file format itself is extremely complex and creates a lot of types while running.  Is it possible the pickle file is corrupt?

Comment: Actually, reading the documents, pickles should be backwards compatible, assuming it's not using any formats specific to a particular installation of python (eg, custom classes or libraries that are on one and not the other)

Comment: I imagine if it's using custom libraries with mismatched versions (like, numpy) you could certainly run into data integrity issues.

Comment: I wonder if I got down to Python 2.7 and an older version of Pickle if I could `load()` the file. Do you know if it's possible to download Pickle version 2, and if so where/how can I do that?

Comment: If you tell us what kind of objects are in the pickle, we may be able to help you further.  Pickle itself is backwards compatible for basic objects and just changing the version of Python will probably not help, but you may need to match the environment of other libraries in use.  You mention scientists, so potentially numpy, scipy, etc.

Answer (score -4):

```
import pickle

with open("theFile.p", "rb") as opened_file:
loaded_data = pickle.load(opened_file)
```

Comment: How would changing to `with` help with the value of `pickle.load`?

Comment: Your indentation is also wrong.

Comment: Yeah that does not fix it